# Execute one SSIS Package from Another, but using a DIFFERENT proxy user. Is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have one SSIS Package that must run as `Proxy A` and another that must run as `Proxy B`.  I would love to have the first package run, and, as one of its tasks, execute the second package.  Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does `Package A` need to wait until `Package B` has completed before proceeding?

Comment: Nope.  `Package B` is not called until the last step of `Package A`.  It would work to make `Package B` the second step of the job that calls `Package A`, but it was requested that I make `A` call `B`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the first package use [sp_start_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) to kick off a job that is set up to run the second package. If this is "fire-and-forget", that's all you need to do. If you need to wait until it's completed, things get more messy - you'd have to loop around calling (and parsing the output of) [sp_help_jobactivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188766.aspx)
and use `WAITFOR DELAY` until the run completes.

This is also more complex if you need to determine the actual outcome of running the second package.

Comment: But there is no way to kick off the second package without creating a job or step in a job for it?  Thanks!

Comment: @user468341 - I don't believe so. I think given what you've said, the simplest approach would just be to have two steps in the job that runs `Package A`.